# How to link template of html to start working in django?

Tags: html, css, django, python-3.x

By running this code in normal *HTML* it runs with style also. But whenever I run it in django it runs and just show me a text. I applied `../static/css/animate.css`, `../css/animate.css` and  `css/animate.css` but none of them are working. I made changes in settings.py by giving STATIC_ROOT but still showing me just text.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html');
```

**main url**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/animate.css' %}">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/icomoon.css' %}">
<!-- Simple Line Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/simple-line-icons.css' %}">

<section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" style="background-image: url(../static/images/W1.png);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <div class="text-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                     <h1 class="to-animate">Welcome in the World of White Hats</h1>
                        <h2 class="to-animate">Your Problem with auto Solution</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Comment: What did you set as the settings for STATIC_URL and STATiC_ROOT?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

Comment: I found my answer not through StackOverflow but thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "../static/" from index.html 
Also don't forget to run: "python manage.py collectstatic" before restarting the server